# UPDATE multiple rows with different values in one query

Tags: mysql, go

I want to update multiple rows with different values, in one query. I know somehow this operation in SQL syntax. But implementing it into Go looks a bit confusing to me. For instance, I want to update the status column based on the menu_id column.

My code works for the first row but other rows value changes to null

```
updateSql := "UPDATE tb_menu SET tb_menu.status =( case" // set query statement
condition := " WHERE tb_menu.menu_id IN ("
menuList := []interface{}{} //set empty interface array
//counter := 0
for _, row := range status {
    menuList = append(menuList, row.Menu_id, row.Status, row.Menu_id)
    updateSql += (" WHEN tb_menu.menu_id = ? THEN ? ")
    condition += "?,"

}
updateSql += "end)"
condition = strings.TrimSuffix(condition, ",") // remove last "," from query statement
condition += ") "
updateSql += condition
update, err := db.Prepare(updateSql)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(" error occured on Preparedb function ", err)
    res = false
    defer db.Close()
    return res
}
set, err := update.Exec(menuList...) // query data to db
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error occured while updating menu list ", err)
    res = false
    defer db.Close()
    return res
}
```

Comment: What's the issue? Did you get an error? If so please include it in the question.

Comment: The problem is that the order of arguments in `menuList` is wrong. In the sql the cases come before the where clause. But in you Go menuList you're mixing the arguments for the cases with the arguments for the where clause. So instead of a single argument list you should have two, i.e. `caseargs []interface{}` and `whereargs []interface{}` on each iteration append `Menu_id` and `Status` to `caseargs` and `Menu_id` to `whereargs`. After the loop is done append the two slices and pass them to exec. i.e. `update.Exec(append(caseargs, whereargs...)...)`